# Contour map and directional derivatives

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I am stuck on how to do this problem, I'm not even sure if my solutions for questions 1 and 2 are even correct.
[image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.  Ref:https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116050/259305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 2 are correct. Just do the same for 3. $(-\vec{i}-\vec{j})$ means that you need to go along the diagona from the upper right corner towards the lower left corner

Comment: So $(-\vec{i}$ means along the x axis and $-\vec{j})$ is the y axis correct?
What is an easier way to read $(-\vec{i}-\vec{j})$ so that on the top of my head I automatically know it should be from the upper right corner towards the lower left corner?
Also, could you post how you would write out #3 just like how I did? So I can understand it better.

Comment: $+\vec{i}$ is along the x axis to the right, $-\vec{i}$ is to the left. Same for $+\vec{j}$ is up, $-\vec{j}$ is down. So $-\vec{i} -vec{j}$ is down and left

Comment: Does the denominator affect the direction at all?
Also, for #4, what does the "-2" do to $\vec{j})$?

Comment: only the sign is important. The magnitude is there just for the size of the derivative, it will not change the sign